# Cannot open xterm as another user : Xt error: Can't open display: :0

Tags: su, display

I'm trying to open an xterm as another user :

```bash
$ su - michel 
$ xterm
No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
$ exit
$ sudo su - michel 
$ xterm
No protocol specified
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :0
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to use `sudo` followed by `su` if you can use `su` itself.

The problem is that the other used isn't allowed to use the `$DISPLAY`. You don't want arbitrary users to connect to your display. If you really want to allow other users to connect to your display, you must also give them access to your `$XAUTHORITY` file. Usually your `$XAUTHORITY` file doesn't contain information for more than one display, so you could just make the file content accessible to the target user  or copy the file.

You can also extract the information and merge it into the target user's `$XAUTHORITY` file. The comment from @mosvy suggests `ssh`, but `su` also works.

```
xauth extract - $DISPLAY | su sebastien -c 'xauth merge - <&7' 7<&0 </dev/tty
```

Comment: I want another user to access my display, how do I do that ?

Comment: @SebMa it's in the xauth(1) manpage `xauth extract - $DISPLAY | ssh other_user@localhost xauth merge -`

Comment: @mosvy I'm not using `ssh`, I'm using `su` to log in as another, otherwise I'll have to be root to be able to install `sshd`

Comment: You don't need `ssh` you just have to make the content available to the other user. I added an example to do that with `su`.

Comment: @RalfFriedl `su: must be run from a terminal`

Answer (score 1):

When you do the **`su`**, it discards the **`DISPLAY`** environment variable (which is used to tell the terminal where to display its window).  If you set **`DISPLAY`**, you will run into a different problem (essentially *permissions*) which has been asked more than once, e.g.,. [X “Can't open display: :0” while DISPLAY variable is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67111/x-cant-open-display-0-while-display-variable-is-correct/67125#67125) (noting that one was incorrectly marked as a duplicate for yet another related issue).

Answer (score 0):

I finally came across this command and now it works :

```bash
$ xhost local:$USER
non-network local connections being added to access control list
$ sudo su - michel -c "xterm -e 'sleep 1'"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried literally every solution from all similar questions.
None of them works.
However, a solution I found [here](https://my.oschina.net/emptytimespace/blog/106756) (Written in Chinese) solved.

You just need to delete `~/.Xauthority` and restart the shell.

Everything works great after relogin.

Comment: Once you login again the missing values are reset. Look at the other answers to this question to see how to handle `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY`