# Ubuntu on Windows Powershell "Can't open display"

Tags: ubuntu, putty, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Powershell on Windows 10. I installed XMing and PuTTY and configured them so that X11 forwarding is turned on. After all this, and installing x11-apps and running xeyes, it tells me "Error: Can't open display: 0.0". I tried changing the DISPLAY to 0 and 'localhost:0.0, but nothing. I installed several packages, many of which will probably end of being unnecessary. I've tried just about everything in the responses both of these questions:
[X "Can't open display: :0" while DISPLAY variable is correct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67111/x-cant-open-display-0-while-display-variable-is-correct?newreg=2fece9554c164efd90a2726a9c526fb5)
[Can I launch a graphical program on another user's desktop as root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/can-i-launch-a-graphical-program-on-another-users-desktop-as-root), but

```
who | awk -v user="$target_user" '$1 == user && $2 ~ "^:" {print $2}'
```

returns nothing and `xhost +` gives me the same display error. I tried various configuration files such as xauth, /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config. It might be important to note that `xinit` returns the fatal error `no screens found` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` shows many errors

```
dbus-core: error connecting to system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound (Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory)
open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
No devices detected.
```

I need to be able to use image tools like ds9 for my research and have been unable to do so, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are you using wsl 1 or 2?

Comment: I was using WSL 2, but after seeing that that complicates the configuration I converted to WSL 1, still with the same problem except now `xinit` gives the fatal error `parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Input/output error)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with the above comment. The problem was that I had installed WSL2, but configuring Ubuntu as WSL1. I was able to run xeyes successfully (and pass all pertinent smoke tests) when I reverted to WSL1 and added

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1
```

to `~/bash.rc`